# Converting a String type to specific DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

How do you convert a string such as `"2017-12-25T03:31:03.150-08:00"` into a `DateTime`?

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse`. Look them up in the MSDN docu. Or search SO. or Google. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have to follow a *predefined pattern* while parsing `string` to `DateTime`, use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)); in your case:

```
  string source = "2017-12-25T03:31:03.150-08:00";

  DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(source, 
    "yyyy-M-d'T'HH:mm:ss.fffzzz", 
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I've put `M-d` (not `MM-dd`) since the example in the question doesn't provide enough information if *month* and *day* must have *leading zeroes* or not.